# How to instantiate a COM object using interop in Delphi Prism

Tags: delphi, com-interop, oxygene

What is the correct syntax for instantiating a COM object in Delphi Prism using COM interop - new does not seem to do the job.

I've added it as a reference to the website project.  Here is the relevant code:

```
method _Default.Button1_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var
   FModel: MarketBuilderLib.MarketBuilderModel;
begin
  FModel := New MarketBuilderLib.MarketBuilderModel;
end;
```

Fails to compile with the message:

```
Error 1 
(PE190) "MarketBuilderLib.MarketBuilderModel" is an interface and cannot be 
instantiated
```

I understand the message but not sure how to do it.  Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attempt to instantiate your COM object by using the [CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method in the System.[Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4wc81dc.aspx) class. The equivalent code might look like this:

```
var
  FModel: MarketBuilderLib.MarketBuilderModel;
begin
  FModel := (MarketBuilderLib.MarketBuilderModel)Activator.CreateInstance(GetTypeFromProgID("{PROG ID}"));
end;
```

Note that you will need to get the type from [GetTypeFromProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypefromprogid.aspx) using the Program Identifier otherwise you will generate an [InvalidComObjectException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.invalidcomobjectexception.aspx).